# Sich mit Themen befassen wie.. [Dativ?]

Tags: dative, nominative

> Ich befasse mich mit Themen wie Datenbankprogrammierung und Interaktionsmodelle.

vs.

> Ich befasse mich mit Themen wie Datenbankprogrammierung und Interaktionsmodelle**n**.

Bezieht sich "mit" nur auf das Wort "Themen" oder auch auf das, was danach kommt? "Datenbankprogrammierung" und "Interaktionsmodelle" sind ja die Themen. Welcher ist der richtige Satz?

Comment: I'm not German, found this question interesting, so I googled "mit Themen wie", both variants (Nom., Dat.) appear.

Comment: Leider ist die Frage geschlossen... Die zwei Sätze mal ausgeschrieben: 1. "Ich befasse mich mit Themen wie Datenbankprogrammierung und ich befasse mich mit Themen wie Interaktionsmodelle" - 2. "Ich befasse mich mit Themen wie Datenbankprogrammierung und ich befasse mich mit Interaktionsmodellen." Das "mit" bezieht sich immer auf beides. Jetzt kommt es darauf an welche Bedeutung der Satz haben soll.